# Elegant way to sort, make unique and eliminate duplicates in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Of course I can sort an array `sort()`, eliminate duplicates `array_unique()` and eliminate blanks `array_filter()`. I could do that in three lines, and then repeat those three lines for the ten arrays I have to process.

But I wanted it to be at least slightly elegant, so I tried to *combine* all three operations. It did work for the first two, then I pushed it too far and applied the sort()

```
$testArray = sort(array_filter(array_unique($testArray)));
```

This produced:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

So what would be the most elegant way to accomplish this array processing goal?

Bonus points for helping me understand why it failed.

Comment: create a function that calls those three functions and call your function on all the arrays you need?

Comment: @Jan Hančič - Yes that could work, I suppose that just seems an amazing thing to have to do for something so simple? I half wondered if there was already a built in function that does this?

Comment: the sort function takes the array by reference `bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )`, so that's why it doesn't work in strict mode. the question is why do you have so many different arrays in the first place, that seems to be a design problem .

Comment: What you are doing is way to specific to be a function in the standard lib. That's why it's not there.

Comment: @xander ...they are being built during the parsing of an XML file. I suppose I could combine the arrays, but it's a quick one of job.

Comment: @Jan Hančič Yes I guess so. Just seems so "ordinary" that one would want unique, non-blank, sorted values from an array - But I guess not! :)

Comment: As for why it failed. `sort` function performs in-place sorting, meaning that it mutates variable instead of creating the new one. without the named variable sorting will be useless as you won't be able to access the result.

Comment: @sevavietl Thanks for that most illuminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a prove of concept you can kind of avoid creating in-between variables and mutating the original array. Take a look at [`SplMinHeap`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splminheap.php) from [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). You can use this class for immutable sorting:

```
$testArray = iterator_to_array(array_reduce(
    array_filter(array_unique($testArray)),
    function ($heap, $element) {
        $heap->insert($element);
        return $heap;
    },
    new SplMinHeap
));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/194094922cfe29cd9ae71b6e32ba173b15763cae).

Comment: More than proof of concept, it worked perfectly as a function, and has solved my problem which is only for internal code anyway, so thanks a lot! Super interesting approach too!

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$testArray = sort(array_filter(array_unique($testArray)));` doesn't work as you expect due to a misuse of [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function:

1. `sort()` returned values are `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Not an array as you expect.
2. `sort()` elements of the recived array parameter will be arranged on the array itself. So it needs an actual array to work on it; not the resturned value of other functions, which doesn't really exists as a variable. That's the reason of the error

   > Only variables should be passed by reference in...

Knowing that, and having in mind that in PHP [the value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) . a first approach to fix the error might be:

```
sort($testArray = array_filter(array_unique($testArray)));
```

...but it won't work either. The assignment return the value of $testArray, not $testArray itself. Same problem as before.

At this point, the easiest way of solving so without unnecessary overhead: use two lines of code instead of one.

```
$testArray = array_filter(array_unique($testArray));
sort($testArray);
```

Test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ef36107ef6f4836c82f64afb78cd59b5b5fd0ae).